# Problem solving with JavaScript nested loops

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays arr1 and arr2:

```
const arr1 = [
  {
    "test_id": 1,
    "type_cd": "C",
    "status_cd": "C"
  },
  {
    "test_id": 2,
    "type_cd": "C",
    "status_cd": "C"
  },
  {
    "test_id": 3,
    "type_cd": "C",
    "status_cd": "C"
  },
  {
    "test_id": 4,
    "type_cd": "C",
    "status_cd": "C"
  },
  {
    "test_id": 5,
    "type_cd": "C",
    "status_cd": "C"
  },
  {
    "test_id": 6,
    "type_cd": "C",
    "status_cd": "C"
  }
];
```

arr2:

```
const arr2 = [
  [
    {
      "resume_id": 200278,
      "test_id": 1,
      "resume_type_cd": "O",
      "status": "Approved - Post Pending",
      "resume_status_cd": "APPR"
    },
    {
      "resume_id": 200286,
      "test_id": 1,
      "resume_type_cd": "C",
      "status": "Chief Review",
      "resume_status_cd": "NAPR"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "resume_id": 200296,
      "test_id": 2,
      "resume_type_cd": "C",
      "status": "Chief Review",
      "resume_status_cd": "NAPR"
    },
    {
      "resume_id": 200298,
      "test_id": 2,
      "resume_type_cd": "O",
      "status": "Approved - Post Pending",
      "resume_status_cd": "APPR"
    }
  ],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  []
];
```

I want to modify arr1 to have resume_id based on the test_id and attach status_cd and type_cd in the arr1 obj will become resumeIds resume_type_cd and status.

Here's what I have tried:

```
for(let i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
  let arr =[];
  for(let j=0;j<arr2.length;j++){
    for(let k=0;k<arr2[j].length;k++){
         if(arr1[i].test_id === arr2[j][k].test_id){
      arr1[i].resume_id = arr2[j][k].resume_id;
      arr1[i].type_cd = arr2[j][k].resume_type_cd;
      arr1[i].status_cd = arr2[j][k].status;
    } 
    }
  }
}
```

Current output:

```
[{"test_id":1,"type_cd":"C","status_cd":"Chief Review","resume_id":200286},{"test_id":2,"type_cd":"O","status_cd":"Approved - Post Pending","resume_id":200298},{"test_id":3,"type_cd":"C","status_cd":"C"},{"test_id":4,"type_cd":"C","status_cd":"C"},{"test_id":5,"type_cd":"C","status_cd":"C"},{"test_id":6,"type_cd":"C","status_cd":"C"}]
```

Expected output:
Basically I want to only consider objects in the final array for which the resume_id exists for a test_id. Thus the output array will only have test_id: 1 and 2 with their resume_ids not 3,4,5, and 6.

```
[
      {
        "test_id": 1,
        "resume_id":200278,
        "type_cd": "O",
        "status_cd": "Approved - Post Pending"
      },
        {
        "test_id": 1,
        "resume_id":200286,
        "type_cd": "C",
        "status_cd": "Chief Review"
      },
      {
        "test_id": 2,
        "resume_id": 200296,
        "type_cd": "C",
        "status_cd": "Chief Review"
      },
      {
        "test_id": 2,
        "resume_id": 200298,
        "type_cd": "O",
        "status_cd": "Approved - Post Pending"
      }
    ];
```

Comment: Is it a must getting the expected result using nested loops?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

- Before getting the result, it is needed to make 2d array `arr2` into 1d array and that can be done using `Array.reduce`.

```js
const arr1 = [
  {
    "test_id": 1,
    "type_cd": "C",
    "status_cd": "C"
  },
  {
    "test_id": 2,
    "type_cd": "C",
    "status_cd": "C"
  },
  {
    "test_id": 3,
    "type_cd": "C",
    "status_cd": "C"
  },
  {
    "test_id": 4,
    "type_cd": "C",
    "status_cd": "C"
  },
  {
    "test_id": 5,
    "type_cd": "C",
    "status_cd": "C"
  },
  {
    "test_id": 6,
    "type_cd": "C",
    "status_cd": "C"
  }
];

const arr2 = [
  [
    {
      "resume_id": 200278,
      "test_id": 1,
      "resume_type_cd": "O",
      "status": "Approved - Post Pending",
      "resume_status_cd": "APPR"
    },
    {
      "resume_id": 200286,
      "test_id": 1,
      "resume_type_cd": "C",
      "status": "Chief Review",
      "resume_status_cd": "NAPR"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "resume_id": 200296,
      "test_id": 2,
      "resume_type_cd": "C",
      "status": "Chief Review",
      "resume_status_cd": "NAPR"
    },
    {
      "resume_id": 200298,
      "test_id": 2,
      "resume_type_cd": "O",
      "status": "Approved - Post Pending",
      "resume_status_cd": "APPR"
    }
  ],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  []
];

const arr2Modified = arr2.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (cur.length > 0) {
    acc.push(...cur);
  };
  return acc;
}, []);

const result = arr1.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const existedItems = arr2Modified.filter((item) => item.test_id === cur.test_id);
  
  existedItems.forEach((item) => {
    acc.push({
      test_id: cur.test_id,
      resume_id: item.resume_id,
      type_cd: item.resume_type_cd,
      status_cd: item.status
    });
  });
  
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this using loops, you could use the [continue statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue)